# Picture In Certain Cells In Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code to tag offset cells if selected cells have picture above them. Code executes correctly and speedily for small selection. However  it slows down if the selection is large. Can it be optimized? Is there a way to loop through only selected cells instead of moving through entire collection of shapes in a worksheet? Code:

I have tried following code with intersection method unsuccessfully:

```
Sub findCellsWithShapes()
Dim sh As Shape, isect, rng As Range, n As Integer
n = 1
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shape
        Set isect = Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, Selection)
            If Not isect Is Nothing Then
               If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = Selection(n) Then
                  Selection(n).Offset(0, 30) = "Yes"
               End If
            Else
               If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = Selection(n) Then
                  Selection(n).Offset(0, 30) = "No"
               End If
            End If
                 If n < Selection.Cells.Count Then
                    n = n + 1
                 Else
                    Exit For
                 End If
     Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: I have already tried using intersect method but it does not give accurate results if cells other than selected cells have picture above them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the site where optimizing code is mainly performed. SO is about fixing broken code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

I just remove some of your loops in order to reduce computation.

```
Sub tagging2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Dim m As Long
Dim arr() As String
Dim Sample As String

m = 1
ReDim arr(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    arr(m) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
    m = m + 1
Next

For Each rng In Selection
    Sample = rng.Address
    For m = 1 to ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
        If Sample = arr(m) Then
              rng.Offset(0, 30).Value = "Yes"
              Exit For
        End If
    Next m
    If IsEmpty(rng.Offset(0, 30)) Then rng.Offset(0, 30).Value = "No"
Next
End Sub
```

I can not compare with your original one.
Anyhow, I think that intersection should be faster. How are you selecting?

Hope it helps

Comment: Tested it. Runs perfect. Tried to modified code so as to remove variable "Sample" in your code and instead compare rng.address with arr(m) directly but it slows down the code a bit so using Sample variable is inevitable it seems.

Comment: Intersection not working when cells other than selection have objects. Following code tried unsucessfully: Sub findCellsWithShapes()
Dim sh As Shape, isect, rng As Range, n As Integer
n = 1
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shape
Set isect = Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, Selection)
If Not isect Is Nothing Then
If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = Selection(n) Then
Selection(n).Offset(0, 30) = "Yes"
End If
Else
If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = Selection(n) Then
Selection(n).Offset(0, 30) = "No"
End If
End If
If n < Selection.Cells.Count Then
n = n + 1
Else
Exit For
End If
Next sh
End Sub

Comment: I can not check your intersection code... Please, edit your question and ad there.